# А(,) нет —нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, междометие

`Иисус? А(,) нет, это ящерица.`

`А(,) нет, показалось.`

И могут ли запятые не ставиться? И почему нужны / не нужны?

Comment: https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CmoiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCFwoVChMKA3JlcRIMCgog0LAg0L3QtdGCMAA=

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за ссылку. А возможен вариант с запятой?

Comment: Возможен. Междометие А со значением узнавания/понимания, пауза.

Comment: @Sharon То есть если союз А будет не с этим значением, то А НЕТ будет являться единым междометием?

Comment: Такого междометия нет,  Без запятой союз А и слово НЕТ. По контексту надо смотреть, если трудно разлчить.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> Иисус? А нет, это ящерица.

> А нет, показалось.

Так, и только так.

Comment: Почему же? Почему нельзя с запятой?